# access 2010 vba recordset updates

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

New to Access VBA with extensive Informix SQL background.  I have a recordset that includes record from 4 tables.

Based upon different situations, I want to update records in three of these tables with data from the fourth table.

I also want to add records to a comment table and output to reports. Can and how do I do this: Code follows:

```vb
Sub query_records_sql()

'Comments: Use the results of a SQL string and to update and add records as required

Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSql As String

' Open pointer to current database
Set dbs = CurrentDb()

strSql = ""

'Create record set for tmp_peo records that have matches in main/prime/sub tables
strSql = " Select * FROM ((tmp_peo INNER JOIN tbl_prime ON (tmp_peo.prime = tbl_prime.prime)) " & _
" INNER JOIN tbl_sub ON (tmp_peo.sub = tbl_sub.sub)) " & _
" INNER JOIN tbl_main ON (tmp_peo.ship = tbl_main.ship_id) AND " & _
" (tbl_prime.prime_id = tbl_main.prime_id) AND (tbl_sub.sub_id = tbl_main.sub_id)"

' Create recordset based on SQL
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSql)

Do While Not rst.EOF
  If (tmp_peo.prime_nomenclature = tbl_prime.nomenclature) Then
   If (tmp_peo.sub_nomenclature = tbl_sub_nomenclature) Then
    If (((tmp_peo.quantity = tbl_main.quantity) Or (tmp_peo.quantity Is Null And tbl_main.quantity Is Null)) And
     ((tmp_peo.sked_a_mdb = tbl_main.sked_a_mbd) Or (tmp_peo.sked_a_mdb Is Null And tbl_main.sked_a_mdb Is Null)) And
     ((tmp_peo.swbs = tbl_main.swbs) Or (tmp_peo.swbs Is Null And tbl_main.swbs Is Null)) And
     ((tmp_peo.rdd_to_ptc = tbl_main.rdd_to_ptc) Or (tmp_peo.rdd_to_ptc Is Null And tbl_main.rdd_to_ptc Is Null)) And
     ((tmp_peo.ptc_bedd = tbl_main.ptc_bedd) Or (tmp_peo.ptc_bedd Is Null And tbl_main.ptc_bedd Is Null)) And
     ((tmp_peo.peo_ships_am_rdd = tbl_main.peo_ships_am_rdd) Or (tbl_peo.peo_ships_am_rdd Is Null And tbl_main.peo_ships_am_rdd Is Null)) And
     ((tmp_peo.sked_a_date = tbl_main.sked_a_date) Or (tbl_peo.sked_a_date Is Null And tbl_main.sked_a_date Is Null)) And
     ((tmp_peo.sypd = tbl_main.sypd) Or (tmp_peo.sypd Is Null And tbl_main.sypd Is Null)) And
     ((tmp_peo.parm_bedd_date = tbl_main.parm_bedd_date) Or (tmp_peo.par_bedd_date Is Null And tbl_main.parm_bedd_date Is Null)) And
     ((tmp_peo.yard_actual = tbl_main.yard_actual) Or (tmp_peo.yard_actual Is Null And tbl_main.yard.actual Is Null)) And
     ((tmp_peo.delivered_quantity = tbl_main.delivered_quantity) Or (tmp_peo.delivered_quantity Is Null And tbl_main.delivered_quantity Is Null)) And
     ((tmp_peo.shipment = tbl_main.shipment) Or (tmp_peo.shipment Is Null And tbl_main.shipment Is Null))) Then
     ' Output to 'No Update Required' Report
    Else
     ' Update main with tmp_peo data
     Call update_main
     Call add_main_comment(tbl_main.main_id, "PRG", =DATE(), "MAIN RECORD UPDATED DURING WEEKLY PEO SKED A UPDATE PROCESS")
     'Output to 'Main Record Updated' Report
    End If
   Else
     'Update sub nomen with tmp_peo.sub_nomen
     Call update_sub
     Call add_main_comment(tbl_main.main_id, "PRG", =DATE(), "SUB RECORD UPDATED DURING WEEKLY PEO SKED A UPDATE PROCESS")
     'Output to 'Sub Record Updated' report
   End If
  Else
      'Update prime nomen with tmp_peo.prime_nomen
      Call update_prime
      Call add_main_comment(tbl_main.main_id, "PRG", =DATE(), "PRIME RECORD UPDATED DURING WEEKLY PEO SKED A UPDATE PROCESS")
      'Output to "Prime Record Updated' report
  End If

  rst.MoveNext
Loop

'Close recordset
rst.Close

'Close Reports

'Open action required report

strSql = ""

'Create record set for tmp_peo records that have no matches in main/prime/sub tables
  strSql = " Select tmp_peo.* WHERE tmp_peo.id Not In " & _
" (Select * FROM ((tmp_peo INNER JOIN tbl_prime ON (tmp_peo.prime = tbl_prime.prime)) " & _
" INNER JOIN tbl_sub ON (tmp_peo.sub = tbl_sub.sub)) " & _
" INNER JOIN tbl_main ON (tmp_peo.ship = tbl_main.ship_id) AND " & _
" (tbl_prime.prime_id = tbl_main.prime_id) AND (tbl_sub.sub_id = tbl_main.sub_id)"


dbs.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: What happens with that code?

Comment: I have not tested it yet - still working my way through and trying to understand vba at this point

Comment: Just posted a revised question regarding these issues with revised code that  compiles on stepping in

Comment: Run time error -424 object required lands on the first If statement in the Do While Not EOF rst.EOF

Comment: Run time error -424 object required lands on the first If statement in the Do While Not EOF rst.EOF – If tmp_peo.prime.nomenclature = tmp_peo.prime_nomenclature = tbl_prime.prime_nomenclature

Comment: Looks like I have to define each piece of the record set  and I'm not sure how to go about doing that

Comment: Where you have `tmp_peo.prime_nomenclature = tbl_prime.nomenclature`, I think your intention is to compare two fields in the current recordset row.  But it doesn't work like that and Access will complain first about `tmp_peo` and later about `tbl_prime`.  I think you need something like this instead ... `rst!prime_nomenclature = rst!nomenclature`  See the *Referencing a Recordset Field* section at [Recordsets for Beginners](http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php/Recordsets_for_Beginners#Referencing_a_Recordset_Field)

Comment: If that is the case, I have two tables with 19 fields each and two tables with three fields each.  Does that mean I have to identify parameters for each of these fields and use those parameters in all the code that deals with this multi table record set?

Comment: I have taken the time to develop a set of queries to run in a sequential order to produce the required adds/updates I want.  I am trying to avoid the DoCmd.RunSQL because I don't believe it will allow me to perform transaction rollbacks if errors are encountered. Also, I'm not keen on doing things before they should be done to ensure I capture the correct data.  For example, I have had to add comment records to a table before performing the actual updates that are required.

Comment: I don't see why you should need query parameters in either of those `SELECT` examples.

Comment: Actually, I developed the queries at the outset of this project to understand what needed to be accomplished.  Then I started working to develop the VBA to mimic what my queries accomplished.  After reading the Recordset info you referenced, I see now what I need to do - Thank you so very much !!

Comment: I am going to attempt this and I will let you know if I can get it to work - thanks again.

Comment: Help - me again.  I'm not sure I can do that since the tmp_peo table and the tbl_main table each contain fields of the same name.  The tbl_main table also contains fields with the same names as those in the tbl_sub and tbl_prime tables.

Comment: That is a pitfall of `SELECT *`.  Instead of `*`, you can explicitly list the fields you want and assign different aliases to the duplicate fields: `SELECT tmp_peo.fld1 AS peo_fld1,  tbl_main.fld1 AS main_fld1, ...` and so forth.

Comment: Instead of select *,  I changed it to something like this :
I did this, but now I get 3296 runtime error -> JOIN expression not supported - sorry to be such a pain, but this has me beating my head against the wall

Comment: Select 't_id', 't_ship', 't_prime', 't_primenomen', 't_sub','t_subnomen', " & _
" 't_qty', 't_sked_a_mdb', 't_swbs' ,'t_rdd_to_ptc', 't_ptc_bedd', 't_peo_ships_am_rdd', " & _
" 't_sked_a_date', 't_sypd', 't_parm_bedd_date', 't_yard_actual', 't_delivered_qty', " & _
" 't_shipment','t_comment', " & _
" 'p_primeid', 'p_prime', 'p_primenomen', 's_subid', 's_sub', 's_subnomen', " & _
" 'm_id', 'm_shipid',

Comment: Forget about VBA for now.  Just create a query in the query designer.  After  you get a working query there, then you can recreate the same statement with your VBA code.

Comment: That is where I started this project.  Al my queries work and now I am trying to convert them into VBA.  I am currently attempting your suggestion to define the fields with the "as"